# mod_rewrite rule not taking effect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below apache config for my app, I want to set a rule such that when the URL contains `fname` parameter it should rewrite to `/v1/documents` along with all Query parameters in the url. In all other cases it should rewrite to `http://localhost:8003/v1/documents` along with query params. Please help.

```
   ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    Timeout 2400
    ProxyTimeout 2400
    ProxyBadHeader Ignore

    RewriteEngine ON
    # for old bugtrack style url compatibility
    RewriteRule ^/(.\d+)$ /goto/$1 [R]

    # to handle /v1/ routes containing uri in old bugtrack
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} uri=(other-document/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^/v1/documents http://localhost:9000/download.xqy?file=%1 [P]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} bn=(.\d+)$
    RewriteRule ^/bug-details\.xqy$ /goto/%1? [R,L]

    ######################### 
    this rule is not taking effect, THE URL is going to proxypassmatch
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !fname=
    RewriteRule ^/v1/documents /v1/documents [QSA,R,L] 
    ########################

    ProxyPassMatch /v1/.*$ http://localhost:8003
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9050/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=2400 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9050/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
# after : this rule is not taking effect, THE URL is going to proxypassmatch
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fname=
RewriteRule !^/?v1/documents/?$ /v1/documents [QSA,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?v1/documents - [L]
```

Comment: Change the test in the RewriteRule or add an other query strinf flag test. I edit my answer with the first one.

Comment: not working, error is gone but the its now back to my original issue. Its going to proxypassmatch

Comment: You add my 2 RewriteRule ?